# javascript/php single quote

Tags: php, javascript, json, quote

i'm trying to this:

```
<?php $php_array = array ('var1' => "l'ape"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var my_javascript_object = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>');
</script>
```

I got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".
The problem is the single quote in the value of var1 in $php_array.

This doesn't work

```
 <?php $php_array = array ('var1' => "l\'ape"); ?>
```

Comment: That works just fine for me. Even without escaping the quote.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to parse your [json](/questions/tagged/json) with JSON.parse in this case. Just use it as an object literal instead of a Javascript string:

```
var my_javascript_object = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to put the JSON in a JavaScript string.

Do this instead:

```
var my_js_obj = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

A JSON string is a valid JavaScript expression which you can simply put directly in your JS code.

---

If you really wanted to create a string containing JSON (**you don't!**), you'd do it like this:

```
var my_json_string = <?php echo json_encode(json_encode($php_array)); ?>;
var my_js_obj = $.parseJSON(my_json_string);
```